# Firebase Storage Triggers in Google App Engine

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-storage

I am trying to figure out how to properly connect Google App Engine instances to Firebase Storage Triggers. In my use case, I want each time a video is uploaded to the Firebase Storage, to be transcoded and then readded to that same database.

I can't figure out, however how one goes about properly connecting Firebase Storage to Google App Engine (and succesfully linking).

My plan in Google App Engine, upon a fresh upload to trigger a simple transcoding function, and readd it

```
def transcode():
    client = storage.Client(PROJECT_ID)
    bucket = client.bucket(PROJECT_ID)
    blob = bucket.blob('sample.mp4')
    with open('/tmp/sample2.mp4', 'w') as f:
        blob.download_to_file(f)
    os.system('rm /tmp/output.webm')
    ret = os.system('/usr/bin/avconv -i /tmp/sample2.mp4 -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis /tmp/output.webm')
    if ret:
        sys.stderr.write("FAILED")
        return "Failed"
    blob = bucket.blob('output.webm')
    blob.upload_from_file(open('/tmp/output.webm'))
    sys.stderr.write("SUCCESS")
    return "SUCCESS"
```

The last time I need to figure out is how to do this when a new upload is added to a Firebase Storage. Is there a correct way to connect google app engine instances to the Firebase Cloud Store (and only have one instance triggered per upload)

Answer (score 2):

It's conventional to use [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/) to communicate items of work between components in Google Cloud Platform.

In the Cloud Function, you would use the [Cloud Pub/Sub SDK for node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/pubsub) to send a message to your application running in GAE.  Then, in GAE, you would [listen and respond to messages](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages).

How you actually do this with configuration and code is heavily dependent on the way you need your system to work.

Comment: okay okay. Gotcha. My only one fear is Google App Engine accidently responding to the same event twice somehow

Comment: Why would that happen?